# How to return a PDF file from in-memory buffer using FastAPI?

Tags: python, pdf, amazon-s3, boto3, fastapi

I want to get a PDF file from s3 and then return it to the frontend from FastAPI backend.

This is my code:

```py
@router.post("/pdf_document")
def get_pdf(document : PDFRequest) :
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    file=document.name
    f=io.BytesIO()
    s3.download_fileobj('adm2yearsdatapdf', file,f)
    return StreamingResponse(f, media_type="application/pdf")
```

This API returns `200` status code, but it does not return the PDF file as a response.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the entire file data are already loaded into memory, there is no actual reason for using `StreamingResponse`. You should instead use [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response), by passing the file bytes (use [`BytesIO.getvalue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue) to get the bytes containing the entire contents of the buffer), defining the `media_type`, as well as setting the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header, so that the PDF file can be either viewed in the browser or downloaded to the user's device. For more details and examples, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728386/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71643439/17865804). Related answer can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76197700/17865804).

Additionally, as the [`buffer` is discarded when the `close()`method is called](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO), you could also use FastAPI/Starlette's [`BackgroundTasks`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) to close the `buffer` after returning the response, in order to release the memory. Alternatively, you could get the bytes using `pdf_bytes = buffer.getvalue()`, then close the buffer using `buffer.close()` and finally, `return Response(pdf_bytes, headers=...`.

### Example

```py
from fastapi import Response, BackgroundTasks

@app.get("/pdf")
def get_pdf(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()  # BytesIO stream containing the pdf data
    # ...
    background_tasks.add_task(buffer.close)
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="out.pdf"'}
    return Response(buffer.getvalue(), headers=headers, media_type='application/pdf')
```

To have the PDF file downloaded rather than viewed in the borwser, use:

```py
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="out.pdf"'}
```

Comment: Tested with a local file I get AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'encode' error

Comment: That should be `buffer.getvalue()` to get the bytes containing the entire contents of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

My buffer and the code to send pdf as a downloadable link in http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs
add this in headers dictionary
"content-type": "application/octet-stream"

```
async def convert_img_to_webp(img):
    image_io = BytesIO()
    image = Image.open(img)
    image.convert("RGB")
    image.save(image_io,"PDF")
    image_io.seek(0)
    # BackgroundTasks.add_task(image_io.close)
    return image_io


@router.post("/image/")
async def upload_file(file:UploadFile):
    if file:
        data = await convert_img_to_webp(file.file)
        headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="sample.pdf"',"content-type": "application/octet-stream"}
        return StreamingResponse(data,media_type='application/pdf',headers=headers)
    else:
        print("file not found")
        return
```