# FastAPI - return contents of csv file as plain text

Tags: python, fastapi

Wondering if anyone can help me out please.

In FastAPI I want to set up an endpoint which returns the contents of a generated csv file as plain text. **I don't want the file to be downloaded.**

I've tried the following which works just fine however a file download is always initiated.

```
  @app.get('/hosts/last_hour')
        def hosts_last_hour():
            epoch_start=time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())-3600
            epoch_end=time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())
            process_hosts(epoch_start,epoch_end)
            
            def iterate_csv(epoch_start):
                with open(f'output/hosts_traffic_{int(epoch_start)}.csv',mode='rb') as csv_file:
                    yield from csv_file

            response = StreamingResponse(iterate_csv(epoch_start), media_type="text/csv")
            return(response)
```

I need the contents of the file to be sent in the response body as text/csv (don't want a downloaded to be initiated and don't want the response in json format). Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

José

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053557/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586180/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655118/17865804).

Comment: Thanks. this led me in the right direction. The solution is to ensure you pass 'Content-Disposition':'inline' in your response header. I'll be posting the solution.

Comment: Why use `time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())` rather than just `time.time()`?

Comment: @SamMason you're right. thanks for pointing that out. changed to time.time()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for a similar solution, here's what worked for me (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804) for more details):

```
# 1 MB chunks    
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 
    
    @app.get('/hosts/')
        
        async def hosts():
            tenant=TENANT
            # Get data for period based on MAX_QUERY_PERIOD (default=3600s)
            epoch_start=time.time()-MAX_QUERY_PERIOD
            epoch_end=time.time()
    
            process_hosts(epoch_start,epoch_end)
            
            async def iter_file():
                async with aiofiles.open(f'output/hosts_traffic_{int(epoch_start)}.csv',mode='rb') as csv_file:
                    while chunk := await csv_file.read(CHUNK_SIZE):
                        yield chunk
            
            headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline'}
            response = StreamingResponse(iter_file(), media_type="text/csv",headers=headers)
    
            return response
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804), regarding returning data using a `StreamingResponse`.

Comment: fixed it so the csv_file doesn't remain open. I'll be testing this out with a larger data set to see what kind of response times I get. Thanks!

Comment: just editted the answer I posted as fastapi was taking forever to return the contents of the csv file. Reading the file in chunks did the trick.

Thank you all for your help and attention.

Answer (score 0):

This will be easy using pandas:

Juast read the csv into a DataFrame using **pd.read_csv** and then turn the DataFrame into a dict using the **to_dict()** function.

Do note that pandas DataFrames can cause memory issues.

```
import pandas as pd
 
@app.get('/hosts/last_hour')
def hosts_last_hour():
   df_data = pd.read_csv("SampleCSVFile_11kb.csv")
   dict_data = df_data.to_dict()
   return dict_data
```

If you don't want to use pandas then do this:

```
import csv
import json

@app.get('/hosts/last_hour')
def hosts_last_hour():
    data_dict = []
 
    with open("data.csv", encoding = 'utf-8') as csv_file_handler:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file_handler)
        for rows in csv_reader:
            data_dict.append(rows)

    return json.dumps(data_dict)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. As I don't want to use Pandas I turned to the second method. Unfortunately this outputs as json. I do have a solution that I'll be posting.